# How can I convert a large file from MP4 to MOV?

Tags: mp4, conversion

I recorded a 5 minute video with my phone, it is a 565M MP4 file. I need to submit it as MOV, specifically. All online converters reject the file as 'too large' and all downloadable programs cost at least $20, which I don't want to spend on a single file. Is there a (legal) way to do it? I'm using Windows 10 and have no access to a Mac.

Comment: ffmpeg is a free command line tool and can do it. Get executable files from http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: You could try just changing the file extension. No, really; mp4 and mov are pretty much the same thing so this 'one weird trick' often works. But since you said "submit", don't rely on it without testing first.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a graphical user interface you can use the free [MediaCoder](https://www.mediacoderhq.com/download.htm) for Windows.

In the `Video` Tab choose `Format` `H.264`.

`Audio` Tab > `Format` `LC-AAC`.

`Container` Tab > `Container` `MOV`.